# "Pure" and "Impure" functions - what's the point?

Tags: vhdl

I am trying to understand the logic behind separating "pure" and "impure" functions. Summarising the LRM, a Pure function will always return the same value with the same given parameters, whereas an impure function may not. So I understand the difference in definition and functionality. I'm just trying to understand why they were separated in the first place.

I'm asking because in the case of a generic function, an interface that specifies a pure generic function can only be assigned a pure function, and an impure generic function can only be assigned to an impure function. This appears to limit the viability of generic functions and requires the author to limit the scope of the use of his code, when he may have no care how the end user wants to use his code.

Here is a practical example, that won't compile because of pure requirements (note in ActiveHDL, you need the -disable87 switch on vcom):

```vhdl
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

entity adder is
  generic (
    --impure function transform(a, b : integer) return integer
    function transform(a, b : integer) return integer
  );  
  port (
    clk       : in  std_logic;
    ip1, ip2  : in  integer;
    op        : out integer
  );
end entity;

architecture rtl of adder is
begin
  adder_proc : process(clk)
  begin
    if rising_edge(clk) then
      op  <= transform(ip1, ip2);
    end if;
  end process;
end architecture;


library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

use std.textio.all;

entity tb is
end entity;

architecture sim of tb is
  impure function add_with_debug(x,y : integer) return integer is
    variable l : line;
    
  begin
    write(l, to_string(x) & " + " & to_string(y) & " = " & to_string(x+y));
    writeline(OUTPUT, l);         -- forces function impure
    return x + y;
  end function;
  
  signal clk          : std_logic := '1';
  signal ip1, ip2, op : integer;
begin

  clk <= not clk after 5 ns;
  
  uut_inst : entity work.adder
  generic map (
    transform   => add_with_debug      -- illegal if transform is not declared impure, because add1_with_debug is impure 
  )
  port map (
    clk     => clk,
    ip1     => ip1,
    ip2     => ip2,
    op      => op
  );
  
  stim_proc : process
  begin
    for i in 0 to 10 loop
      ip1 <= i;
      ip2 <= i+20;
      wait until rising_edge(clk);
    end loop;
    std.env.stop(0);
    wait;
  end process;
end architecture;
```

and how about a more esoteric example using the same entity:

```vhdl
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

library osvvm;
context osvvm.osvvmContext;

use std.textio.all;

entity tb2 is
end entity;

architecture sim of tb2 is
  shared variable rand  : RandomPtype;
  
  signal clk          : std_logic := '1';
  signal ip1, ip2, op : integer;
begin

  clk <= not clk after 5 ns;
  
  uut_inst : entity work.adder
  generic map (
    transform   => rand.randInt      -- illegal if transform is not declared impure
  )
  port map (
    clk     => clk,
    ip1     => ip1,
    ip2     => ip2,
    op      => op
  );
  
  stim_proc : process
  begin
    for i in 0 to 10 loop
      ip1 <= i;
      ip2 <= i+20;
      wait until rising_edge(clk);
    end loop;
    std.env.stop(0);
    wait;
  end process;
end architecture;
```

In my experience, there has never been a "penalty" to making a function impure, and for all practical purposes functionality is the same. The only reason most designers add `impure` to their functions is because the compiler told them to. And in the case of protected types, impure functions are practically a requirement.

So why are they separated?

Comment: Pure functions can be optimised in many ways that impure functions cannot : for example, I hope you can see a problem with replacing "now" with a pre-compiled constant... It should be possible to use a pure function where an impure one is called for (if you need to call it from an "impure" wrapper function, that's annoying but not catastrophic).

Comment: I think this is my question - is the separation purely one of tool optimisation and not actually something the user really needs to know? So from a VHDL point of view theres actually no real difference when you call them. With modern tools, can they not do the optimisation without having to be told from the code?

Comment: The standard is replete with examples of semantics making more sense to the experienced language implementer than the end user. A generic function is instantiated independently of the environment in which it is declared. Requiring the impure caveat alleviates the necessity of elaborating function calls individually and resolving non-parameter environment. It's a statement on implementation effort.

Comment: @Tricky   If Brian's case does not work, be sure to submit it as a language issue for the next revision.

Comment: @JimLewis I think Brians case is the easiest (if not only) work around. But there is no way to work around the opposite situation where you have a generic block with a pure generic function and you want to connect an impure function. Ive already raised an issue for the next revision, suggesting that restrictions are lifted, or pure and impure definitions are removed (less likely as it might not maintain backwards compatability)

Comment: It should not be possible to instantiate a pure generic function with an impure actual fn. And there should be no workaround for that case : if an impure actual is needed, the generic should be specified as impure. However I can see a case for allowing a pure actual for an impure generic (without a wrapper!) as that should be harmless as far as I can see.

Comment: @BrianDrummond Im really asking if pure/impure definitions should be removed all together. I cannot see any reason why someone would specify a pure over an impure, as they appear to be have defined purely for the tool designers at the time they were first introduced. Times move on and I am fairly confident tools can now work out whether a function is pure/impure entirelyfrom the code (compilers already tell you to make functions impure where neccessary).

Comment: I feel it is an unneccessary restriction on designers. If I pick up some code I want to use from somehwere, and they have specified a generic function without the impure keyword, I am restricted solely to pure functions. I would bet any money that the designer had no reason for making it pure, other than it was one less word to write and they didnt consider an impure function as a possibility. The only way to fix this is change the source. If I have no access to do this, Ill have to re-write the entire codebase myself, limiting reusability.

Comment: Or maybe as a compromise, the restrictions on connecting functions in generics should just be removed.

Comment: And that pure specification tells you something about how the generic is intended to work. A clean abstraction with no side-effects, no state, no unintended assignments or any of the things you can bury in impure functions. Like the difference between a VHDL constant and a C const : you can rely on the constant not changing. It might in hindsight have been better to make impure the default and allow the programmer to add Pure the way you add Constant, as a restriction (as Ada does with "pragma Pure") but doing that now would break compatibility.

Comment: @Tricky  It does not hurt to ask the compiler folks.   No promises with mapping an impure function to a pure though.   It would be interesting to allow resolution functions to be impure.    There we could have some fun.

Comment: @JimLewis I've made a feature request of aldec for the -relax switch on vcom to ignore pure/impure mappings. They also fixed a crash mapping a protected type function to generic function on a package.  Looking forward to experimenting mapping protected type functions to other protected type generic functions.